# OuputCapture with multiple tests

Tags: testing, spring-boot

I am using org.springframework.boot.test.OutputCapture to test an annotation that logs something.

It works brilliantly for a single test and when tests are run individually if there a multiple tests using output capture in a source file, but when multiple tests are run together only the first test run gets the captured output, the others get empty strings.

Is there any way to avoid this, I can't see any configuration possibilities?

This is a simplified test illustrating the problem
    import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnit;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoRule;
import org.springframework.boot.test.OutputCapture;

/** 
 * Simplest implementation that illustrates my problem using {@link OutputCapture}. 
 * <p>
 * If both tests are run, the second test run will not have any output captured so fails. 
 * If tests are run individually they both pass.
 * <p>
 * It is somehow related to 
 * 1) mocking with mockito which is not actually needed in this simplified implementation: without @InjectMocks no output is captured at all and both test fail. 
 * 2) if use System.out.println not log4j, both tests pass and output is captured without mocking as well. 
 */
@FixMethodOrder // done to illustrate error
public class OutputCaptureTests {

    @Rule 
    public OutputCapture outputCapture = new OutputCapture();

    @InjectMocks 
    private InternalTestListener listener;// = new InternalTestListener();

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Test 
    public void test1() {

        listener.doIt( 1 );
        assertThat( outputCapture.toString() , containsString( "doIt "+1 ) );
    }

    @Test 
    public void test2() {

        listener.doIt( 2 );
        assertThat( outputCapture.toString() , containsString( "doIt "+2 ) );
    }

    static class InternalTestListener{

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger( InternalTestListener.class );

        public void doIt( int x ){

            LOGGER.info( "doIt "+x );
//            System.out.println( "doIt "+x );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? We use OutputCapture in several places in Boot's own tests and don't have the problem that you've described.

Comment: I have add a test case to the original question. Seems to be related to mocking, see comments in the test case.

Comment: Both tests pass for me. They also pass when I remove `@InjectMocks`. Given that it works for you when you use `System.out` and it always works for me, I would guess that the problem lies somewhere in your logging configuration.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and I resolved it like following:

Specifically was missing **follow="true"** to be added in the Console appender:

```
<Appenders>
<Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
  ...
</Console>
```

In my case, as @Andy Wilkinson mentioned, was a configuration problem.

Comment: What file in Spring Boot do you add those lines? I tried adding follow="true" to "resources/log4j.properties" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

To expand a bit on @Iker's answer..

The `OutputCapture` rule sets up a new `SystemCapture` instance and associates it with the variable that you use to capture the output (`outputCapture` in the OPs code).

The `SystemCapture` constructor resets the value of `System.out` and `System.err` to buffers that capture the output:

```
SystemCapture() {
    this.out = new PrintStreamCapture(System.out, this::captureOut);
    this.err = new PrintStreamCapture(System.err, this::captureErr);
    System.setOut(this.out);
    System.setErr(this.err);
}
```

The `follow="true"` setting ensures that the log4j appender sends the message to the current value of `System.out` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71158324/3059685).

If `follow` is false (the default) then it tries to send it to the old (stale) value of `System.out` and in my case this resulted in an exception: `org.springframework.boot.test.system.OutputCaptureRule@xxxxx (renderer threw IllegalStateException)`.