# What is the purpose of log4j ConsoleAppender follow parameter?

Tags: log4j2, consoleappender

In the example I am following, there is a line that goes like this in the log4j configuration file:

`<Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">`

I understood everything in this line except for `follow="true"`, I have read the description of this particular parameter on the official website: [**This Website**](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#:%7E:text=follow,used%20with%20direct.). I also tried searching in other websites, but to no avail.

The description goes like this:
[image: follow parameter]

This description got me confused, What do they mean by "honors reassignments....." , what is its purpose, what happens if I change it to `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `System.out` property is not read-only and can be reassigned through [`System#setOut`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)). With `follow="true"` the appender will send the message to the **current** value of `System.out`, whereas with `follow="false"` logs will be sent to the original value of `System.out`.

You can test the two behaviors with:

```java
      // This performs automatic initialization
      final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Log4j2Test.class);
      // System.out is attached to the JVM's `stdout`
      logger.warn("Sent to 'stdout'");
      // Reassignement of System.out
      System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("file.log")));
      // System.out is attach to the file 'file.log'
      logger.warn("Sent to 'file.log'");
```

From a practical perspective performance with `follow="true"` is worse than with `follow="false"` and `System.out` is **rarely** reassigned.

Comment: So, I tried your example, and this is the behavior that I saw: with `follow="false":` The `logger.warn("Sent to 'file.log'");` was thrown in the console, and the log file was empty. with `follow="true"`: The `logger.warn(.....)` was thrown in the file, after being created. So, if I have to make `follow=false`, how am I supposed to write to a file, using Rolling File Appender, or, is the purpose of setting `follow="true"` is to write to a file, in xml syntax.

Comment: @SpaceSloth: in the example above I redirect `System.out` to a file only for demonstration purposes (so you can see what happends if `System.setOut` is called). It is not a good practice. If you want to log to a console (terminal), use the `ConsoleAppender`. If you want to log to a file, use the `(Rolling)FileAppender`. As you can see in the documentation the latter does not have a `follow` property, this is characteristic to the console appender.

Comment: My problem here is that most examples use console appender like this 
`<Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
</Appenders>`

And I actually have Rolling file appender 

`<RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="logs/log4j2-demo.log"
                     filePattern="logs/log4j2-demo-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">`

Comment: With a rolling file appender there is no `follow` attribute. It opens a file for writing and always sends messages to that file until rollover occurs.