# How to assert org.slf4j.Logger statements with junit?

Tags: java, junit, log4j, slf4j, spring-boot-test

How can I validate log statements from a `org.slf4j.Logger` with `junit` in a `spring-boot-test`?

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    private final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    
    public void run() {
        LOGGER.info("running");
    }
}

@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        service.run();
        
        //TODO how to validate log statement?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution with Springs `@ExtendWith(OutputCaptureExtension.class)`:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = "logging.level.root=INFO")
public class LogServiceTest {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Test
    @ExtendWith(OutputCaptureExtension.class)
    public void testLogging(CapturedOutput capture) {
        logger.info("junit"); //can be replaced with any service call that logs
        assertThat(capture.getOut()).contains("junit");
    }
}
```

It requires the `follow="true"` option on your log4j config:

`<Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">`

Comment: What does `follow="true"` do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71158063/what-is-the-purpose-of-log4j-consoleappender-follow-parameter

Comment: @membersound I was struggling to find a solution for some time now, your solution worked like a charm. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

If the underlying SLF4J is Log4j 2.x, as your tags might implicate, you can use a [`ListAppender`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-core/src/test/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/test/appender/ListAppender.java), which is contained in the `log4j-core`'s `test-jar`.

Comment: I would prefer if testing could be possible without having to introduce a separate dependency just for this usecase.

Comment: @membersound did you find a way to assert logs?

Comment: @RaniSelvaraj see answer above.