# Spring feature OutputCapture does not work in valid spring boot version

Tags: java, spring, junit

I cannot use the feature with `OutputCapture` within [JUnit testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-output-capture-test-utility). I want to use this feature to see some log messages.
If I tried to include the class package `org.springframework.book.test.rule.OutputCapture` in IDEA it shows me warn message "No suggestions". So that I am not able to access to outputCapture class (even test package is not visible).

As I found out on this [website](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/test/rule/OutputCapture.html) this class is supported since version 1.3. 
However I am using correct spring boot version 1.5.

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.rule.OutputCapture; THIS IS NOT RECOGNIZED

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MyTest {

    @Rule
    public OutputCapture capture = new OutputCapture();

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        assertThat(capture.toString(), containsString("World"));
    }

}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you add the junit code?

Comment: What do you mean by "THIS IS NOT RECOGNIZED"?

Comment: This means that if I tried to pick org.springframework.book.test in IDEA it shows me warn message "No suggestions". So that I am not able to access to outputCapture class. I will edit my question.

Comment: have you added in your configuration (maven?) the dependency to spring boot test? please show your `pom.xml`

Answer (score 4):

The `OutputCapture` class was [deprecated](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/test/rule/OutputCapture.html) in version 2.2.0 in Spring Boot test in favour of the `OutputCaptureRule` class.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61268662/3059685) for how to use `OutputCaptureRule` class.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wide guess since I don't know your dependencies: if you are using maven, try to add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version> <!-- or another version -->
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The reason is that `OutputCapture` comes along from the project `spring-boot-test`.

Github: [OutputCapture](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/rule/OutputCapture.java)