# How do you use LoggingListener in JUnit 5 to capture log output

Tags: java, testing, junit

Section 4.7 of the JUnit user manual (https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-capturing-output) talks about capturing standard output/error using listeners, and the following section says that the API already contains a class called `LoggingListener`. I can create one using:

```
LoggingListener listener = LoggingListener.forJavaUtilLogging(Level.INFO);
```

but I'm not sure how to proceed after that. I want to capture the log output happening at INFO level. I already added

```
junit.platform.output.capture.stdout=true
junit.platform.output.capture.stderr=true
```

to `junit-platform.properties` under `src/test/resources`, as it says to do. The listener class contains a method called `reportingEntryPublished` which takes a `TestIdentifier` and a `ReportEntry`, but I'm not sure how to use that, assuming that's even the right method to call.

Any advice would be appreciated. The User Manual section makes it sound easy, but I can't find any examples anywhere (including in the tests of the source code on GitHub).

BTW, suggestions from both ChatGPT and Bard are hilarious.

Comment: I haven't used the LoggingListener but I've had success with the OutputCapture, although I've run into issues with timing... Check this out, might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439151/how-to-unit-test-logging-error-with-spock-framework-in-groovy/61268662#comment134910935_61268662

Answer (score 0):

In this simple example we create two tests, create custom `TestExecutionListener` which prints the content of `ReportEntry`, and execute the tests using configured `Launcher`. This launcher registers our custom listener and set-up properties.

```
package test;
    
    //imports...
    
    public class MyTest {
    
        @Test
        public void test1() {
            System.out.println("System.out.println: test1()");
            System.err.println("System.err.println: test1()");
        }
    
        @Test
        public void test2() {
            System.out.println("System.out.println: test2()");
            System.err.println("System.err.println: test2()");
        }
    
        public static class CustomListener implements TestExecutionListener {
    
            @Override
            public void reportingEntryPublished(TestIdentifier testIdentifier, ReportEntry entry) {
                Map<String, String> entryMap = entry.getKeyValuePairs();
                if(testIdentifier.isTest()) {
                    System.out.println("Captured: " + testIdentifier.getDisplayName() +
                            ", stdout: " + entryMap.get("stdout").trim() +
                            ", stderr: " + entryMap.get("stderr").trim());
                }
            }
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
                    .selectors(selectPackage("test"))
                    .configurationParameter("junit.platform.output.capture.stdout", "true")
                    .configurationParameter("junit.platform.output.capture.stderr", "true")
                    .build();
            try (LauncherSession session = LauncherFactory.openSession()) {
                Launcher launcher = session.getLauncher();
                launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(new CustomListener());
                TestPlan testPlan = launcher.discover(request);
                launcher.execute(testPlan);
            }
        }
    }
```